# Problem when trying to connect to wireless Wifi and Ethernet Ubuntu-23.10.1

Tags: ethernet, deja-dup

[Image of wireless networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RR0v.jpg)

[Image of what happens when I click on any wireless network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dca0I.jpg)

I have a problem with the internet connection in Ubuntu (DualBoot), as you can see in the images, when I click on a wireless network it sends me to the NETWORK window, then when I try to connect the network cable it does not take it , I left it connected by entering Windows and if it takes it in Windows. When I installed Ubuntu, during the installation process it let me connect to a wireless network, but now it doesn't let me.

Comment: The language on AskUbuntu is English. Please translate your question.

Comment: Lo siento, pero aquí solo se puede preguntar en ingles. Si quieres, puedes usar herramientas como Google translate, pero en todo caso, tendrás que preguntar en ingles.